# gtmetrix site problems: remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL

Tags: wordpress, seo

My gtmetrix Speed Grade is 65% ! Gtmetrix recommendation is in below image:
[image]

First recommendation: `Remove query strings from static resources`
How to remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using "W3 Total Cache" plug-in then you need to un-select- "Prevent caching of objects after settings change" in Browser Cache.

I was also facing the same issue, it got resolved.